# Common lines from 2 files based on 2 columns per file

Tags: sorting, unix, join, awk, overlap

I have two file:

file1:

```
1   imm_1_898835    0   908972  0   A
1   vh_1_1108138    0   1118275 T   C
1   vh_1_1110294    0   1120431 A   G
1   rs9729550   0   1135242 C   A
```

file2:

```
1   exm1916089  0   865545  0   0
1   exm44   0   865584  0   G
1   exm46   0   865625  0   G
1   exm47   0   865628  A   G
1   exm51   0   908972  0   G
1   exmF    0   1120431 C   A
```

I want to obtain a file that is the overlap between file 1 and 2 based on columns 1 and 4,and I would print the common values for columns 1 and 4 and also columns 2 for file1 and file2.

e.g

I want:

```
1   908972  imm_1_898835    exm51
1   1120431 vh_1_1110294    exmF
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$4]=$2;next} (($1,$4) in a){print $1,$4,a[$1,$4],$2}' file1  file2
```